# Reset page Number mpdf for footer

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm Working with mPDF on my project and now stuck on this problem. 
First let me describe my PDF structure:

- First page is a cover page.
- Second page to seven or eight dynamic page is Table Of Content page.
- After Table Of Content page Main content page.

So the problem is:

There is header,footer,page number in cover page and TOC page. How do I remove that? The content page number start with no 8. How do I reset it to become no 1?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but [the docs](https://mpdf.github.io/) should help you to configure the page layout of your PDF the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset it to become no 1 by using resetpagnum parameter:

```
<pagebreak resetpagenum="1">
```